# How can I keep one title for two different values?

Tags: jquery, css, drupal-7

I need help figuring out how to keep one title for two different values that have the same title.  I am using the cms drupal.  I am creating a calendar when you hover over the dates a pop up of the events shows up.  In the view, I have a field that has a title, and the event.  Rewrite Field code looks like this:

```
<div class ="event-title">EVENTS FOR [field_event_date_2]</div> 
<div class ="main-event">[title] @ [field_event_date]</div>
```

When there is only one event the pop up looks correct and has the title of the date and the event below it. Like this: [one event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZsSK.png)
When I 2 events for the same day in the calendar I get a title for each event, meaning I get two titles.  like this [2 events two red titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLmMX.png)

*using the beautytips and calendar pop up modules in drupal for the hover effects

I only want one red main title and the the two events below.  Let me know if anyone has any idea if i can do this in drupal view or how i would do this with jquery or if there is another simpler way.

Comment: Try moving the first div up so it is only called once?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here.... by moving the div up you mean up in another field? I have tried this and its always called with the event still end up getting duplicates

Comment: Where did you place the div with your first title? Are you using theming templates?

Comment: I am using a drupal view and added the classes inside of a field